# SaaS service uses OIDC and SAML 2.0 and customer only supports OAuth 2.0, what options do we have to make this work?

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, openid-connect, access-token

I'm currently applying for a job as a Sales Engineer, and I have everything else regarding their APIs, product, presentation skills and more covered but my understanding of SSO isn't great so trying to improve there.
I've done some investigating and tried to learn about it, but I have nobody to bounce questions with hence starting this thread. Adding some context below.

Participants in the authorization:

SaaS service - supports OIDC and SAML 2.0 today

Partner - Supports OAuth 2.0 today, but is open for options

My job is to present how to get the SSO working, and go through the options options available.

I've done a fair amount of reading and investigating on my own, and as I understand it OIDC is built on top of OAuth 2.0 adding a few more feature. And looking at the API calls for both standards it seems like they both contain an access_token, adding one OIDC and one OAuth 2.0 example taken from various tutorials:

**OIDC example response**

```
{
  "access_token":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1...Iiwia2lkIiA6I",
  "expires_in":3600,
  "refresh_expires_in": 0,
  "token_type":"Bearer",
  "not-before-policy": 0,
  "scope":"urn:transaction:carbon urn:transaction:freshwater"
}
```

**OAuth 2.0 example response**

```
{
   "scope":"cn",
   "expires_in":599,
   "token_type":"Bearer",
   "refresh_token":"534310ab-570b-4eb4-0ed7-d01d243fae21",
   "access_token":"238beab2-b545-4fee-80fa-63f224bc56f6"
}
```

Does this mean that OIDC is backwards compatible, e.g. we just configure the SaaS' OIDC setup to communicate with the Partners Oauth 2.0 server, skip "scope:openid" in the request, we get the access_token, validate it and then all is set? Or does this simply not work for an unknown reason? And are there any other options I should look into here?

Answer (score 0):

good on you for trying to learn and actually understand a complicated technical topic. And doing some digging instead of posting a broad generic question here.

You're right in that OIDC is a layer built on top of OAuth 2.0. The key thing to understand (and never forget) is that OAuth is for *authorization* while OIDC is for *authentication*.

Authorization refers to what the user is authorizing/allowing the client (or app) to do on the user's behalf or the things the user is allowing the app to have access to.

Before OIDC, the user would have to authenticate with the authorization server, but the client/app would have no info about who it was that authenticated. It just gets the access token back which says that some user ID is allowing access to certain resources.

OIDC provides a way to give that context. It added the ID token which is similar to the access token in that it's typically also a JWT, but the info is about the identity of the user whom authenticated. And it also provided an endpoint (/userinfo) that the client could hit and get info about that user.

So, it's not really that OIDC is backwards compatible. If you don't request an OIDC scope or token, then you're just doing OAuth.

In the first example response labeled as OIDC, I don't see an ID token nor do I see an OIDC scope. While it still could be OIDC (use that access token to get info from the /userinfo endpoint, but this would still need some OIDC scope) , it doesn't look like it from what you've shared.

Comment: I've done some more digging and as you say the answer to "Is it backwards compatible" is "no". However I see that OIDC and SAML both supports "seamless login", eg skipping the authentication page if the user ID already logged in and simply redirecting them back to the SaaS service again while OAuth2.0 doesn't support this. Am I correct in this understanding? And another question I have, is it feasible to have multiple SSO solutions in this scenario (eg both OAuth & OIDC) or is it as simple as that a migration from OAuth to OIDC or SAML is required to support "seamless login" here? I guess so?

Comment: You're referencing SSO or Single Sign On. Sign on once, and you don't need to sign on again when navigating between sites that have established this SSO trust or network. OAuth supports this as well, but they must all be OAuth clients, i.e., not mix with OIDC if you want to guarantee SSO. Going from OAuth to OIDC is not a huge deal. And you can mix those. But, it'll depend on how things are set up if you need to sign on again to get the OIDC features. OAuth/OIDC to SAML is pretty different.